# Tensorflow contrib.summary API - recording scalars every n-th step does not work properly

Tags: python, tensorflow

Recently I have started playing out with TensorBoard. Firstly, I've just wanted to do a simple visualization of the loss function over a few hundred steps. For that, I've wanted to use the `tf.contrib.summary` API.

My code works except for a slight annoyance - let's say that I want to perform 250 steps of optimizer and I want to record the loss on each of these steps, so, I will do something like this (some chunks of code are missing).

```py
graph = tf.Graph()
sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)

with sess.graph.as_default():
    ... # lines that define the computation graph as well as input dataset and predictions
    global_step = tf.train.create_global_step()

    rmse = tf.math.sqrt(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=Y, predictions=Y_PRED))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(rmse, global_step=global_step)

    # create summary writer, tensor for recording scalar and initialize everything
    summary_writer = tf.contrib.summary.create_file_writer(args.logdir, flush_millis=10 * 1000)
    summaries = {}

    with summary_writer.as_default(), tf.contrib.summary.always_record_summaries():
        summaries["train_rmse"] = tf.contrib.summary.scalar("train/RMSE", rmse)

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    with summary_writer.as_default():
        tf.contrib.summary.initialize(session=sess, graph=graph)

for i in range(250):
    train_X_batch, train_Y_batch = # ... retrieve batch of data from dataset
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X : train_X_batch, Y : train_Y_batch})
    sess.run(summaries["train_rmse"], {X: train_X, Y: train_Y})
```

But when I do this, and then visualize results in tensorboard, my `train_rmse` was recorded only 241 times instead of 250 times as I've used the `tf.contrib.summary.always_record_summaries()`, right? (See the image).

[image]

This issue seems to be data dependent. When I try similiar thing on the mnist dataset and try to record some scalars for the same amount of steps, the number of recorded steps was something like 200.

I've tried to find the answer in the tensorflow documentation but without success. I've also checked things like not having enough data for the 250 steps - this should not be an issue.

One more thing is that this happens even when I use the `record_summaries_every_n_global_steps(n)` call. For example, calling it with `n = 5` records steps only up to the 215th step.

Could anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Did you try adding writer.close() at the end of your script?

Comment: Tried just now, but it did not help. But valid guess nevertheless, I should've not overlooked that.

Comment: Maybe adding a `writer.flush()` before closing would change something https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255855/tensorflow-filewriter-not-writing-to-file

Comment: Nope, still the same. Something like that related to the writer should not be an issue though, as the program ends right away after all of the iterations.